# How can I apply the Poisson ($\mu$) distribution to two series of random draws?

Tags: poisson-distribution, approximation, poisson-binomial-distribution

I have the following question:

A box contains 1000 balls, of which 2 are black and the rest are white. If two series of 1000 draws are made at random from this box, what approximately, is the chance that they produce the same number of black balls?

I believe it an exercise in applying The Poisson ($\mu$) Distribution: The *Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu$* is the distribution of probabilities $P_{\mu}(k)$ over $\{0,1,2,...\}$ defined by 
$$P_{\mu}(k)=e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!}$$

Let $\mu = 1000 \cdot \frac{2}{1000} = 2$ so that
$$P_{\mu}(k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(k)\cdot P(k)$$
$$P_{\mu}(k)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-2}\frac{2^k}{k!} \cdot e^{-2}\frac{2^k}{k!}$$
$$=e^{-4}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{2^k}{k!})^2$$

And then I look up the answer and see that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{2^k}{k!})^2$ translates to $I_0(4)$ which is a modified Bessel function. However I havn't learnt this, and Bessel isn't in the index of my textbook.

I thought maybe $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{2^k}{k!})^2 = (e^2)^2$$ but that would make the whole thing =1... which maybe makes sense since they question didn't specify with replacement.

Comment: You can't interchange summation and squaring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comments:** I'm not sure why you think you're supposed to use a Poisson
approximation.

***Poisson approximation.*** With your Poisson method, approximating the (infinite?) sum with R:

```
f = dpois(0:10000, 2)
sum(f^2)
[1] 0.2070019
```

But I'm not sure why you'd sum the series beyond 1000 draws?

Actually, almost all of the probability is in the first few terms:

```
f = dpois(0:10, 2);  f.2 = f^2;  cf.2 = cumsum(f.2)
cbind(f, f.2, cf.2)  # 'binds' column vectors

                 f          f.2       cf.2
 [1,] 1.353353e-01 1.831564e-02 0.01831564
 [2,] 2.706706e-01 7.326256e-02 0.09157819
 [3,] 2.706706e-01 7.326256e-02 0.16484075
 [4,] 1.804470e-01 3.256114e-02 0.19740189
 [5,] 9.022352e-02 8.140284e-03 0.20554217
 [6,] 3.608941e-02 1.302445e-03 0.20684462
 [7,] 1.202980e-02 1.447162e-04 0.20698933
 [8,] 3.437087e-03 1.181356e-05 0.20700114
 [9,] 8.592716e-04 7.383478e-07 0.20700188
[10,] 1.909493e-04 3.646162e-08 0.20700192
[11,] 3.818985e-05 1.458465e-09 0.20700192
```

Simulating with 10 million iterations, result is $0.2071 \pm 0.0013.$

```
set.seed(1016)
x = rpois(10^7, 2)
y = rpois(10^7, 2)
mean(x==y)
[1] 0.207069      # aprx P(Same twice) = 0.2070019
2*sd(x--y)/sqrt(10^7)
[1] 0.001264853   # aprx 95% margin of simulation error
```

So provided the Poisson model is correct, the answer to four places is 0.2070.

***Hypergeometric.*** If you choose without replacement, then you'll *always* get exactly 2 black balls.

***Binomial.*** If you choose with replacement, the exact model is binomial.

```
f = dbinom(0:1000, 1000, 2/1000)
sum(f^2)
[1] 0.2071337
```

Maybe there is a nice binomial identity for summing the 1001 terms.

Simulation of binomial model gives $P(\text{Both Same}) = 0.2073 \pm 0.0003,$
which includes the exact value.

```
set.seed(1017)
x = rbinom(10^7, 1000, 2/1000)
y = rbinom(10^7, 1000, 2/1000)
mean(x==y)
[1] 0.207295
2*sd(x==y)/sqrt(10^7)
[1] 0.0002563777
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. For the first method (Poisson Approximation) - how could this calculation be done with a scientific calculator? Or would there be a table that would need to be consulted? Previous to this question I've figured out the probabilities of 1) Less than 2 black ball, 2) exactly 2 black balls, 3) more than 2 black balls - if that helps.

Comment: On a calculator, if you had the patience to sum only 1st 11 terms of series, you'd get close: In R, `f = dpois(0:10, 2); sum(f^2)` returns
0.2070019 because the first few terms are the only large ones. You could see when the squares get too small to matter. // But you should start learning R if this isn't your last prob/stat course. Not _all_ of R. Maybe just a few dozen functions at the start, mostly intuitive.

Comment: FWIW, the Binomial answer can be expressed (with $n=1000$ and $p=2/1000$) as $(1-p)^{2n}\,_2F_1(-n;-n;1;p^2/(1-p)^2).$  It expands to a polynomial of degree $2n.$  Indeed, using the [`hypergeo` library](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015/RJ-2015-022/RJ-2015-022.pdf) `R` (a "scientific calculator" if there ever was one!) will compute `n <- 1000;
p <- 2/1000;
((1-p)^(2*n) * hypergeo(-n,-n,1,(p/(1-p))^2))` as 0.2071337, agreeing with the `dbinom` value to 15 significant digits.  Unfortunately there's only about 10% improvement in computation time.

Comment: FWW (again, now that we're edging toward giving final hwk solutions): For the first few terms of binomial:  `f = dbinom(0:10, 1000, 2/1000); sum(f^2)` returns 0.2071337. // IMHO unless undisclosed directions mandate Poisson aprx, I see no reason to avoid exact binomial computation.